# Firemonkey Form Components distorced on Delphi XE6

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

i have created a firemonkey application but when i execute it, that happens:

[image: Image 1]

AND this is how it should be:

[image: Image 2]

I have no ideia what can that be, could you help me? thanks in advance

> > **Found solution.** <<

I had to use 'dx10 software' just like this on program begin:

```
fmx.types.GlobalUseDX10Software:= true;
```

But now I got an other problem, CPU Usage is very high. When I turn GlobalUseDX10Software ON, It goes up to 50% after a few seconds..

[image]

Comment: I have no idea either, I cannot see your screen, read your code, or read your mind.

Comment: Please read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I also highly advise that you take a look at your previous questions and mark the answers as accepted if they answered your question.

Comment: 1) The title of your question is meaningless. We can tell the question is about Firemonkey and Delphi from the tags you've added, and you could also add a delphi-xe6 tag to show a specific version, which means there is zero information in your subject. 2) We can't possibly debug your code based on two images you've posted here.

Comment: Going to go out on a limb and guess that you are using a TEffect of some kind via the Design View in the IDE? Note that all effects used this way also affect the children controls of the targeted control of the effect as well (e.g., TGlowEffect on a ListBox that contains x amount of ListBoxItems will add a surrounding glow to the ListBox itself and also every ListboxItem as well...). Also note you can not simply stack effects this way either...

Comment: How could I stack the effects in a good way?

Comment: I think your TAniIndicator is causing your effect to calculate every frame which could lead to high CPU.